# SSIS How to ForceExecutionResult Success for the Grandparent Container

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, error-handling, ssis

Your help and insight is greatly appreciated

In SSIS I need to ForceExecutionResult = Success for the Grandparent Container

This is how I have my package set up currently:
Parent Package = A
Child Package = B

- An Execute Package Task calls B from A
- If B fails with a specific error code, I retry B

I retry B by way of the OnError event handler in A's Execute Package Task using a Script Task.

To my way of thinking:
- A's Execute Package Task OnError event handler is the Script Task's Parent Container
- A's Execute Package Task is the Script Task's Grandparent Container

How do I ForceExecutionResult = Success for the Grandparent Container (A's Execute Package Task) when the B retry succeeds?

Right now even when the B retry succeeds, A's Execute Package Task still shows Red = failure as a result of the failure that happens on the first B attempt.

Looking for a programmatic way of doing this with C# or VB inside a script task.

I am using SSIS 2008

Thanks for reading

Comment: I think you will need an external table to set a few flags and stuff. I mean, its doable but its just a bit cumbersome. Since you are retrying to start B after certain failure, the package needs to hold the status and the error code of the 1st run to reference the same during the second (or third or N'th run). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main advise is not to rerun package B after `OnError` event. You need to call B, make sure it does not fail package A, evalute outcome of package B and decide what to do.

1. Create a `For Loop` container and make it run for a set number of times (= max numbers of runs, like in `while i < 5 do`).
2. Set `Execute Package` task not to fail parent and whole package on error.
3. Evaluate execution code in a `Script Task` and exit `For Loop` container on success / failure condition. (like by setting i=5).

Probably you can execute package B from C# `Script Task` - check object model how to do that. I'll update my answer if I find how to.

Comment: thank you for your solution. I believe it is viable. In my particular case (100+ child package calls) it is probably not something I will choose to implement because I am lazy. As I find no way of doing this with C# or VB inside a script task, I am accepting your answer. I do not see how it is actually possible to do what I want with the SSIS 2008 object model. It does not appear to be possible to change the properties of a parent package from a child package. More's the pity.